# Logitech F710 not echoing in ROS Humble

Tags: joystick, teleop, logitech

I have a working Logitech F710 gamepad working on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22 RTOS Humble. Jstest shows the joystick is working. I have added the telepop-twist-joystick node and it loads without errors.

However, ROS2 topic echo /joy shows no data. I have to the best of my ability constructed a logitech.config.yaml file, but I am uncertain of the format is the same, since it looks different from ROS 1 config files.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the yaml file to the question, and the command line you used to launch the teleop node, and if you altered a launch file add that too?

Comment: I wonder if the device id is correct. Do you see the file descriptor inside `/dev` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a `logitech.config.yaml` file for the Logitech F710:

```
teleop_twist_joy_node:
  ros__parameters:
    axis_linear: # Left thumb stick vertical
      x: 1  
    scale_linear: 
      x: 0.3
    scale_linear_turbo: 
      x: 0.75

    axis_angular: # Left thumb stick horizontal
      yaw: 0 
    scale_angular: 
      yaw: 1.0

    enable_button: 4  # Left top trigger
    enable_turbo_button: 6  # left bottom trigger
```

Launches and runs successfully:

```
ros2 launch teleop_twist_joy teleop-launch.py joy_config:='logitech'
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2023-12-
10-22-38-37-019957-ubuntu-1737
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [joy_node-1]: process started with pid [1738]
[INFO] [teleop_node-2]: process started with pid [1740]
[teleop_node-2] [INFO] [1702265918.149934078] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Teleop enable bu
tton 4.
[teleop_node-2] [INFO] [1702265918.150271424] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo on button 
6.
[teleop_node-2] [INFO] [1702265918.150308072] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Linear axis x on
 1 at scale 0.300000.
[teleop_node-2] [INFO] [1702265918.150357830] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for linear
 axis x is scale 0.750000.
[teleop_node-2] [INFO] [1702265918.150383163] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Angular axis yaw
 on 0 at scale 1.000000.
[teleop_node-2] [INFO] [1702265918.150404737] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for angula
r axis yaw is scale 1.000000.
[joy_node-1] [INFO] [1702265918.270255026] [joy_node]: Opened joystick: Logitech
 Gamepad F710.  deadzone: 0.300000
```

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer (you may need to wait 48 hours)